# Can muslims operate animal rescues, animal sanctuaries?

Tags: animals

And this includes taking care of all of Allah's (SWT) creations including dogs, pigs. Sorry if this seems like a very basic question, i just havent really found much useful info anywhere...

Comment: Do zoos in Muslim countries have unclean species on display?